# Adding 'active' class to the li which has a name similar to the one of the page you are on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
// store url for current page as global variable
current_page = document.location.href
// apply selected states depending on current page
if (current_page.match(/home/)) {
$("#krymson_nav ul li:eq(0)").addClass('active');
} else if (current_page.match(/dashboard/)) {
$("#krymson_nav ul li:eq(1)").addClass('active');
} else if (current_page.match(/content/)) {
$("#krymson_nav ul li:eq(2)").addClass('active');
} else if (current_page.match(/modules/)) {
} else { // don't mark any nav links as selected
$("#krymson_nav ul li").removeClass('selected');
};
});
</script>`
```

HTML:

```
<div id="krymson_nav">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="http://blackboarddev.com/new/modules/krymson/dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="http://blackboarddev.com/new/modules/krymson/content.php">Content</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that this worked fine and that the only problem was that I was loading the jquery api wrong :p

Comment: Are you having trouble?  Is there a question?  You can also select elements based on their attributes (e.g. the href) and adjust it's parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line:

```
$("a[href='" + document.location.href + "']").closest('li').addClass('active');
```